# How to calculate season base on startdate and end date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-function, qsqlquery

i would like to added a seasonDescription and season to this temp table 
base on date selection by parameter startDate and endDate compare to catchdate 
seaon define by each year season start from Oct 1 and season end Sep 30 of the follow year 
example if catch date between  Oct 1,2013 to Sep 30,2014 this will be season 2013 and the seasondescripttion will be Oct 1,2013 to Sep 30,2014
i'am thinking to write function to get season base on date selection but don't know how to start. here is my temp table

```
enter code here
If(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempcatch') Is Not Null)/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
  drop table #tempcatch;
create table #tempcatch
(
        [id] int ,
        [customerId]   int,     
        [catchDate]  datetime,
        [submissionDate]  datetime,
        [speciesId] int,              
        [catchStatusId] int,
        [approvedDate]  datetime

  )
INSERT INTO #tempcatch VALUES (1, 123,'01-01-2013','',1,1,'' );
INSERT INTO #tempcatch VALUES (2, 124,'05-30-2013','',1,1,'' );
INSERT INTO #tempcatch VALUES (3, 125, '06-01-2013','',1,1,'' );
INSERT INTO #tempcatch VALUES (4, 126, '07-12-2013','',1,1,'' );
INSERT INTO #tempcatch VALUES (5, 123, '08-01-2013','',1,1,'' );
INSERT INTO #tempcatch VALUES (6, 124, '10-01-2013','',1,1,'' );
INSERT INTO #tempcatch VALUES (7, 125, '10-28-2013','',1,1,'' );
INSERT INTO #tempcatch VALUES (8, 126, '09-10-2013','',1,1,'' );
INSERT INTO #tempcatch VALUES (9, 127, '01-01-2014','',1,1,'' );
INSERT INTO #tempcatch VALUES (10, 128, '02-15-2014','',1,1,'' );
INSERT INTO #tempcatch VALUES (11, 129, '03-10-2014','',1,1,'' );
INSERT INTO #tempcatch VALUES (12, 130, '03-11-2014','',1,1,'' );
INSERT INTO #tempcatch VALUES (13, 131,'04-20-2014','',1,1,'' );
INSERT INTO #tempcatch VALUES (14, 132,'06-29-2014','',1,1,'' );
INSERT INTO #tempcatch VALUES (15, 133, '08-25-2014','',1,1,'' );
INSERT INTO #tempcatch VALUES (16, 134, '07-12-2014','',1,1,'' );
INSERT INTO #tempcatch VALUES (17, 135, '08-01-2014','',1,1,'' );
INSERT INTO #tempcatch VALUES (18, 136, '10-01-2014','',1,1,'' );
INSERT INTO #tempcatch VALUES (19, 137, '12-28-2014','',1,1,'' );
INSERT INTO #tempcatch VALUES (20, 138, '01-10-2015','',1,1,'' );
INSERT INTO #tempcatch VALUES (21, 139, '01-12-2015','',1,1,'' );
INSERT INTO #tempcatch VALUES (22, 140, '02-09-2015','',1,1,'' );
INSERT INTO #tempcatch VALUES (23, 141, '02-20-2015','',1,1,'' );
INSERT INTO #tempcatch VALUES (24, 142, '02-26-2015','',1,1,'' );


select id,customerId,catchDate,submissionDate,speciesId,catchStatusId,approvedDate,'seasonDescription'='','Season'=''

 from #tempcatch
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple case expression should do it.

```
SELECT id
       , customerId
       , catchDate
       , submissionDate
       , speciesId
       , catchStatusId
       , approvedDate
       , '' as 'seasonDescription'
       , case when MONTH(catchDate) >= 10 then YEAR(catchDate) + 1 else YEAR(catchDate) end as Season
FROM   #tempcatch
```

Comment: Wow!!! perfect how i don't think about this. thank you Seasn Lange.  I appreciate the help.